# Laravel Rule:exist() not giving expected behavior

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want user to provide postal code using input text field and despite of the white spaces he/she uses when providing the postal code I want it to pass validation if it is available in my database so I used the following code in my validator:

```
'postal_code' =>['required','string','max:7',Rule::exists('zipcodes','POSTAL_CODE')->where(function ($query) use($postalcode) {

               return $query->whereRaw('replace(POSTAL_CODE,\' \',\'\')=? ',[str_replace(' ','',$postalcode)]);
            })],
        ]);
```

but when I test the form I used it for it show error if I input aaa7fr but no error if I used aaa 7fr which is exactly in my database which I do not want and instead I want both to show no error.
Would you please kindly tell me where is the wrong in my code and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide what kind of error? I mean error msg. And also, In your db you have zipcodes with spaces? or zipcodes are without spaces?

Comment: @KerimTokymtayev in my database I have zipcodes with spaces and the error message under postal code input field is " The selected postal code is invalid."

Comment: may be it will be easier if you update all your zipcodes to be without spaces? and save it in db without any spaces? To do so you may use this template for SQL = UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, ' ', '')

Comment: And After that, $query->where('postal_code',str_replace(' ','',$postalcode));

Comment: @KerimTokymtayev I do not want to duplicate used space to store them since I will have to keep the orginals and use them to display some information on the website using correct format

Comment: I'll consider to use `preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $postalcode);` instead of `str_replace(' ', '',$postalcode);`